# Is there a way to build a string out of an array in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I'm curious as to whether there's a way to build a string out of an array in a specific order. My code so far:

```
var pcontent = [ "h", "H", "o", " " ];
var constpass = strConstruct( "pcontent", 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2);

function strConstruct ( aname ) {

    var newStrs = arguments;
    var cs;

        for ( var i = 1; i < newStrs.length; i++ ) {
            cs = cs + aname[i];
        }
        return cs;
}

console.log( constpass );
```

Upon running it I get "contentundefinedcontent"

If it isn't possible, that would be good to know, thanks

Comment: `cs = cs + aname[i];` => `cs = cs + window[aname][i];`

Comment: I got `undefinedcontentundefined` after running this code.

Comment: You are not passing in the variable, you are reading the string....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just few small mistakes

- You need to pass the variable `pcontent` to `strConstruct` not the string `"pcontent"`
- And `aname[newStrs[i]]` instead of `aname[i]`
- Initializing `cs` to an empty string `var cs = ""`

  ```js
  var pcontent = ["h", "H", "o", " "];
  var constpass = strConstruct(pcontent, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2);

  function strConstruct(aname) {
    var newStrs = arguments;
    var cs = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < newStrs.length; i++) {
      cs = cs + aname[newStrs[i]];
    }
    return cs;
  }
  console.log(constpass);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) as a replacement of arguments.

Later you can map the characters of the string, which is here used instead of an array with the letters.

```js
function strConstruct(string, ...indices) {
    return indices.map(i => string[i]).join('');
}
  
var constpass = strConstruct("hHo ", 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2);

console.log(constpass);
```

Comment: I like the flexibility of this solution, yet when I try to run it I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token ."

Comment: it's a matter of time. soon that will work with es6.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is

```js
var pcontent = ["h", "H", "o", " "],
   constpass = (p, ...a) => a.reduce((s,k) => s+=p[k],""),
      result = constpass(pcontent, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2);
console.log(result);
```